# What is the purpose of primary and foriegn keys, if I can join without defining them?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, constraints

Since I can join two tables without using relational keys (primary and foreign keys), what is the purpose behind defining those keys in the first place?

For example, my first table is

```
customer table
fields are cust_id, lastname, firstname
```

and my second table is

```
product table
fields are product_id, productno, cust_id
```

Even though i did not declare any fields as primary or foriegn keys, I can still join the two tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN product p ON p.custid=c.cust_id
```

Why should I define the keys then?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity

Comment: the use is to let the database help you whenever it can without you having to roll your own the entire way.

Comment: Please ***STOP*** asking the same question over and over and over again! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668323/what-is-the-need-of-primary-and-foreign-key-in-joining-two-tables

Comment: iam sory u r right but that question was closed so i tried same question in different manner after all iam newely created account @marc_s

Comment: When [your question gets closed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15668323/335858) you should not post it again unchanged: you need to edit **the original one** to make it easier to understand, and then it may get reopened. I did not catch your first question, so I answered the duplicate instead. You shouldn't have two identical questions, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been some good answers, allow me to extrapolate a little bit.

As "dasblinkenlight" states, speed of the retrieval (the database knows in advance about the relationship between the two tables and can potentially optimize the query), and more importantly, referential/data integrity.

Let's talk about the second one a bit more.

Consider a simple scenario where you have the following three tables (I have simplified this.  In reality, you'd have the ability to order many products, but I am keeping it simple for brevity):

```
CustomerTable
   ID
   FirstName
   LastName


OrderTable
   ID
   CustomerID
   ProductID    

ProductTable
   ID
   Description
```

Without foreign keys, we are freely able to:

- Create Orders with no Product
- Create Orders with no Customer
- Delete Customers that have Orders
- Delete Orders that have Products
  etc...

**This is a recipe for disaster**

By using foreign keys, we can redesign the above, thusly:

```
CustomerTable
   ID
   FirstName
   LastName


OrderTable
   ID
   CustomerID -> References CustomerTable.ID
   ProductID -> References ProductTable.ID

ProductTable
   ID
   Description
```

We can specify that CustomerID and ProductID are "NOT NULL" (just like other columns).  This means to create an order, we *have* to have an existing customer and an existing product.  Excellent!

But it gets better.  What happens if I start deleting products?  Unless we've specified some cascading options (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#CASCADE)), the database will throw a wobbly and say "Nope.  You can't delete that, it's referenced by something".

This is the *data integrity* part of the equation.  We can't point to something that's not there (A foreign key insists that we point it to nothing [if null is allowed], or something that is there.  The primary key helps us with this).

Suddenly, the database itself is making sure that everything works well together and ties up nicely.  Without it, you could delete all the orders... delete products...  delete anything you wanted, and then your application would wonder what the hell was going on.

Use them :)

Answer (score 3):

The two reasons behind telling your RDBMS that the two keys are related are

- **Speeding up the retrieval** - RDBMS may add implicit indexes to speed up joins when you declare a primary-to-foreign key relation
- **Dealing with referential integrity** - RDBMS can perform a check on deleting a primary key to see if you are deleting a row referenced from "child" records, and optionally delete child records or throw an error. Your RDBMS would also tell you if you try inserting a record with a foreign key that has no matching primary key in the parent table.

Other than that, the keys and the non-key fields can be used in similar ways. In particular, it is certainly alright to join on columns that are not declared as primary or foreign keys.

Answer (score 3):

It's not about "*being able to join*" it's about what's allowed to go into the table. Also, what happens if you delete a Customer, but there's outstanding Products in the database? They'd be what's called **orphaned records** if there was no Foreign Key. The addition of the foreign key, by default **prevents** you from deleting objects that are referenced by child tables.

Answer (score 2):

These concepts are all about constraints.

The `PRIMARY KEY` is a constraint indicates that a set of columns are unique and not `NULL`.  Most implementations use an index to support this and in some implementation the primary key is also the clustering index for ordering the data in pages in disk storage.

A `FOREIGN KEY` is a constraint that indicates that a set of columns refer to another set of columns in another table.  Generally a foreign key can still be `NULL`, but if it is not `NULL`, then it has to be a valid key in the table it references and that also has to be unique.  The key it references DOES NOT have to be the PRIMARY KEY, just a unique key (the database usually determines this from a constraint like a unique constraint or index).  The foreign key itself does not have to have an index, but this is usually a good idea, since removing rows in the table referred to requires all foreign keys to be checked before the deletion can be allowed.  These all fall under the concept of referential integrity.

In general, all constraints on the database protect data integrity and also allow the optimizer to understand the limitations and get more clues as to the best execution plans.  However, it is possible to simply have appropriate unique indexes on a table and still get the same execution plan without the indexes being there as part of a primary key or as a precursor to defining a foreign key reference, but the fact that an index is unique will certainly influence the choice of plan.

There are many things *allowed* in queries (DML), but DDL declares the **structure** of the data.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to backwards-compatibility issues, SQLite *does* allow Null primary keys :(

Comment: @Moo-Juice Yes, it's a pain straddling what ANSI definition says and what different implementations do.  For instance SQL Server allows a `PRIMARY KEY` **and** a clustered index to be defined independently.  MySQL does not let you have a `PRIMARY KEY` and a separate clustered index.  Teradata has a primary key concept for logical model but doesn't care about it compared to it's concept of `PRIMARY INDEX` which it uses for data distribution amongst amps.  And of course ANSI has little to say about indexes at all - **but** it **does** specify that a `PRIMARY KEY` cannot be null, *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, data integrity.

Also using a foreign key like this will make sure that searches happen a lot faster as more data is entered into the table.

Comment: Not always - SQL Server, for example, doesn't automatically add an index on foreign keys, so you still need to add that index to get the query benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Joins are just used on "common variables" therefore joins can then be used to join tables with a value equal to each other in two tables. Primary keys must be unique and therefore you can always reference them, therefore you can also use these as references from other tables. Basically when you are doing a query from 2 tables the thing that happens is a Cartesian product. (this is not happening in real implementation as time is a factor) and this produces much data, however joins reduce the data in your result (in theory).
you can read more on joins here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp